# How I can solve this error on DiscordGuild() dsharpplus

Tags: c#, discord

I am making a discord bot and now I am making a ban command but I got an error on DiscordGuild().
My code looks like this:

```
        [Command("ban")]
        [Description("Ban user")]
        [RequirePermissions(Permissions.BanMembers)]
        [Hidden]
        public async Task Ban(CommandContext ctx,
                     [Description("User banned")] DiscordMember member, 
                     [Description("How many days will ban take?")] int days, 
                     [RemainingText, Description("Reason")] string reason)
        {
            await ctx.TriggerTypingAsync();
            DiscordGuild guild = new **DiscordGuild()**;
            guild = member.Guild;
            try
            {
                await guild.BanMemberAsync(member, days, reason);
                await ctx.RespondAsync($"User @{member.Username}#{member.Discriminator} was excluded by the ADMIN {ctx.User.Username}");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                await ctx.RespondAsync($"User {member.Username} cannot be blocked");
            }
        }
```

and I have this error: 'DiscordGuild' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.
What I have to do to make my code working?
Help me, please!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are trying to create an Instance of DiscordGuild, which doesn't supply an empty constructor. So if you wanted to create a new DiscordGuild instance, you would have to supply the needed parameters, you can check those by hovering over it most of the time. As you are overwriting the instance shortly after anyway i would just try the following

Instead of:

```
DiscordGuild guild = new DiscordGuild();
guild = member.Guild;
```

try the following:

```
DiscordGuild guild = member.Guild;
```

or you could also use a var as well, but that's personal preference:

```
var guild = member.Guild;
```